# XAML Element responsive width on Orientation change

Tags: xaml, responsive-design, windows-phone-8.1

I am building a Windows 8.1 Universal app. On the orientation change for the phone, the outer "Grid" element doesn't change in width when the phone is switched to Landscape mode (and vice versa if the app is originally opened in landscape - doesn't change width when orientation=portrait). The `Width` is bound to the `PivotItem` `Width` and the `PivotItem` fills the entire screen on orientation change but the `Grid` does not.

```
<Page x:Name="page"
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:m="using:App1.Models"
    xmlns:vm="using:App1.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar Foreground="White" Background="{StaticResource CustomResource}">
            <AppBarButton x:Name="BackButton" Label="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                          Click="BackButton_Click" Icon="Back" />
            <AppBarButton x:Name="ForwardButton" Label="Forward" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                          Click="ForwardButton_Click" Icon="Forward" />
            <AppBarButton x:Name="HomeButton" Label="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                          Click="HomeButton_Click" Icon="Home" />
            <AppBarButton x:Name="SettingsButton" Label="Settings" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                          Click="SettingsButton_Click" Icon="Setting" />
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myHeader">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="CustomFont" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="PivotStyle" TargetType="Pivot">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource myHeader}"/>
        </Style>
        <!--<dict:NumberConverter x:Key="myNumberConverter" />-->
    </Page.Resources>

    <d:Page.DataContext>
        <vm:DesignTimeDataSample />
    </d:Page.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Pivot x:Name="MyPivot" 
               Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle}" 
               Background="{StaticResource CustomItem}" 
               SelectionChanged="MyPivot_SelectionChanged" 
               Foreground="Purple"
               Grid.Row="1">
            <PivotItem x:Name="Feed" 
                        Header="news feed" 
                        FontFamily="CustomFont">
                <ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TileStories}" x:Name="cont" Margin="0,10,0,10" Background="{StaticResource CustomItem}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource CustomItem}" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomItem}">
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,10" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource CustomItem}" />
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border CornerRadius="20" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <StackPanel Height="160" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Feed, Mode=OneWay}">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Margin="20"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0.333,53" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                            LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" 
                                                            LineHeight="20" MaxHeight="80" 
                                                            TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                                            Text="{Binding Headline}" FontSize="18" 
                                                            FontFamily="CustomItem" />
                                                    </Grid>
                                                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0.333,0.333,0">
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                    Margin="5" Text="{Binding Date}" 
                                                    Foreground="#FFBDBDBD" 
                                                    FontFamily="CustomItem"  />
                                                        </Grid>
                                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                                            <AppBarButton
                                                        Style="{StaticResource CustomItem}"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                        Margin="0,0,0,2" 
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                                        Icon="Read" 
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding Url}" 
                                                        Click="StoryButton_Click" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </Grid>

                                                </Grid>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                        <Button Foreground="White" Content="Send Notification" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="ToastButton" Click="ToastButton_Click" Margin="0,0,0,25.333"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem x:Name="News" Header="news">
                <WebView x:Name="MyWebView" NavigationCompleted="MyWebView_NavigationCompleted"/>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: why is the width of the outer `Grid` bound to the `PivotItem` width? Grid should scale automatically to screen size. Post the outer Grid xaml as well

Comment: I had to do that because the `Grid` was overflowing outside the bounds of the parent elements. I will edit the original post.